# The Appium desired capabilties code in the constructor of the class gives object null reference error

Tags: c#, appium

I created two different projects. In project 1 I have class that have constructor with following code to setup the *appium server*

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.SetCapability("device", "Android");
capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Platform, "Windows");
capabilities.SetCapability("deviceName", "Soti India (SM-P600)");
capabilities.SetCapability("platformName", "Android");
capabilities.SetCapability("platformVersion", "4.4");
capabilities.SetCapability("appPackage", "net.soti.hub"); // app package 
capabilities.SetCapability("appActivity","net.soti.securecontentlibrary.activities.SplashActivity"); 
driver = new AndroidDriver(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
driver.Context = "NATIVE_APP";
```

Now from  another class in another project I am calling this constructor where I will write my Testmethods also but I am getting `"Object null reference"` *error* at `_AddAppiumCommands() method`

Comment: Could you please provide more info? Code where you call the first project and full exception stack.

Comment: My another class in another project is as follows and project references contains all appium related dependency .: public class

Comment: code in that class is :                                                                    [Testclass]                                                                                                      public class Testclass{ // create object of class where desired capabilities are set for driver} . If the whole code i.e desired capabilties and where the driver is used after setting is in same class then no error.